# Uvm factory registration disambiguation

Tags: factory, verification, uvm, disambiguation

Considering a verification environment that imports 2 packages, pkg_A and pkg_B.

Both packages contain some common class definitions (i.e. same class name, class properties, etc.):

pkg_A.sv

```
class *some_name*;

`uvm_object_utils(*some_name*)
```

pkg_B.sv

```
class *some_name*;

`uvm_object_utils(*some_name*)
```

This makes the same class name to be registered to the factory twice, leading to:

> UVM_WARNING @ 0: reporter [TPRGED] Type name **some_name** already registered with factory. No string-based lookup support for multiple types with the same type name.

Consider that both pkg_A and pkg_B have numerous class with same name. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`uvm_object_registry(T,S)`](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/macros/uvm_object_defines-svh.html#%60uvm_object_registry) or [`uvm_component_registry(T,S)`](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/macros/uvm_object_defines-svh.html#%60uvm_component_registry) registration macros. These macros can appear anywhere in the declaration space of the class declaration of `T` and will associate the string `S` to the object type `T`. These macros are called by the corresponding `uvm_*_utils` macros, so you may only use them if you do not use the `uvm_*_utils` macros. For Example:

```
package A;
  import uvm_pkg::*;
  `include "uvm_macros.svh"
  class myclass extends uvm_component;
    // `uvm_component_utils(myclass)
    `uvm_component_registry(myclass, "A::myclass")
    function new(string name="myclass", uvm_component parent=null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction
  endclass
endpackage

package B;
  import uvm_pkg::*;
  `include "uvm_macros.svh"
  class myclass extends uvm_component;
    // `uvm_component_utils(myclass)
    `uvm_component_registry(myclass, "B::myclass")
    function new(string name="myclass", uvm_component parent=null);
      super.new(name, parent);
    endfunction
  endclass
endpackage

module test;
  A::myclass a;
  B::myclass b;
  initial begin
    a = A::myclass::type_id::create("a", null);
    b = B::myclass::type_id::create("b", null);
  end
endmodule
```

For details to see [Docs of Utility and Field Macros](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/files/macros/uvm_object_defines-svh.html#Utility_and_Field_Macros_for_Components_and_Objects) or [Source Code](https://verificationacademy.com/verification-methodology-reference/uvm/docs_1.2/html/src/macros/uvm_object_defines.svh).